# What may cause the speed of an app to change

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am attempting to make changes to a complex image processing app which employs some C++ code and opencv. I have noticed that its speed can vary by as much as 20% from one run to the next even without me making any changes to the code. Its as if my phone was sometimes in a good mood and other times not. I guess its probably something to do with *other* tasks being carried out by the phone why my app is running (please tell me if you think there are other possibilities).

I wonder if there is anything I could do to make sure the app always runs at the same speed. Perhaps doing something like give my app greater priority over other tasks? Or suppress other tasks?

Comment: Use a profiler and check out your hotpoints.

Comment: I think that's easier said than done when you have a mix of java and C++.

Comment: You can't do much about it as you don't know what the device is doing. Of course you can not suppress or stop other tasks, that would be an inviation for any kind of malware.

Comment: A quick google: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/01/thread-scheduling-in-android.html

Comment: @Mick No one said it is going to be easy. It never is. I hate it when I have to do it, but no one said coding was easy.

Comment: You do understand that for an image processing app, for most of the operations, the speed of a run will be proportional to the image size and resolution ? Right? It would be much easier to pin point your problem if you let us know how you are testing the app's performance and for what type of functions.

Comment: the processing is all on a 640x480 raw image, while doing some object recognition tasks. I am measuring the performance with an on screen frames-per-second display.

Comment: But why would you like to always run the app at the same speed? Isn't it expected that the speed varies if your phone is running other apps at the same time?

Comment: So that I can experimentally make changes and see what effect that has on speed.

Comment: @Mick, unless you uninstall all the other apps and stop any other auto-run services, the best you can get is by using a profiler in a simulator.

Comment: For this reason, OpenCV recommends that you develop your algorithms on a PC. If it's fully done, port it.