# How can I tell if "inline" worked?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a working app which I need to speed up. I set up profiling (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage) for details) which appears to report on how much time each function takes. I can not find a way to discover anything about time consumed in different sub-parts of functions.

I then inserted the keyword "inline" in the declarations of some frequently accessed small functions hoping for some speedup. But when I profiled again, I saw the same list of functions, including the ones I'd made inline. This made me suspicious as to whether the inline keyword had just been ignored.

I have a vague recollection that with some compilers the inline keyword was something that the compiler could optionally ignore, depending on things like the amount of memory available.

So is there some check I could do to confirm whether or not the "inline" keyword has actually done its job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

- examining the compiler's assembly or machine code output (whether disassembling or just checking for the function symbol with `nm` or whatever android has), or stepping through with a debugger
- using a compiler pragma/attribute to force inlining (if available, for example [GCC has a function attribute `always_inline`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)), if your profiling results aren't affected then presumably the compiler was already inlining
- checking your profiling docs to make sure that however you're doing profiling doesn't inhibit inlining

As you recalled, `inline` (and member functions defined inside their class which are implicitly inline) are just hints for the compiler.  Some people argue they're just convenient ways to manage One Definition Rule issues, but you'd have to check individual C++ compilers' code to see if the keyword was really *that* meaningless these days.  The compiler might use all sorts of metrics to work out when to inline, including the optimisation flags in affect, the size of the out-of-line function, the number of calls to the function (e.g. if there's only one, why not inline even a large function?) etc..

Comment: Adding always_inline made the function names disappear from the profile report. That's enough evidence that for me that it previously wasn't inlining and now is :-)

Comment: @Mick: cool - but the million-dollar question is... is it faster? :-)

Comment: I think so, but I have been suffering with this issue to confuse matters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631535/what-may-cause-the-speed-of-an-app-to-change

Comment: @Mick: sounds tricky... 20% is pretty substantial.  I don't know anything about android or OpenCV, so hope others will help you there.  Cheers.